# iOS: UIButton and UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I programmatically implemented a custom UITableViewCell, where in the cellforindexpath, I created a UIButton and UILabel.

For the UIButton, I used the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method to call another method which make a HTTP post request which updates the UILabel text in the server. However, now I want to update the text in the UILabel, instead of reloading the app.

How do I do this?

The problem I have is that UILabel and UIButton are both subviews of UITableViewCell, so there's no direct communication between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you made the label and button are fields of the custom cell you made. Then make the action handler also on the custom cell, you will be able to access the label easily.
It would be something like that:

CustomCell.h

```
   UIButton *button;
   UILabel *label;
   -(IBAction) updateLabel:(id) sender;
```

CustomCell.m

**Update**

```
//[button addAction:@selector(updateLabel)  target:self];
-(IBAction) updateLabel:(id) sender{
[self.label setText:@" text"];
}
```

You can Implement the custom cell using Interface Builder. You can also connect the action to the button from Interface Builder as well, you will need to move the action prototype to the header file. Make the file owner the ViewTableController to load that cell.
Then make an outlet for your custom cell on the TableViewController and on the delegate method you can load the custom cell like that:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cell_identifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell;
    cell=(CustomCell*)[table_view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell_identifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        self.customCell=nil;
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"custom_cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=self.customCell;
    }
}
```

Comment: I programmed the UIButton and UILabel programmatically so there's no CustomCell class...is there another way?

Comment: I tried doing it this way but it was difficult because the CustomCell was a subview of the UITableView so it was complicated.

Comment: Sarah--I'd just make the label a property of the custom cell, in keeping with Apple's current style. Also, you can use UINib to load cells directly without needing a placeholder owner object.